# Form Input with dynamic return type

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

I want to develop a dynamic form input which may be just a UITextField or UIDatePicker. The form input should be initialized with a type (enum) and therefore return either a String or a Date depending on with which type it was initialized. Maybe later I would want to add more specific types returning other things.

What would be best practice to do this with Swift 4 and where would you store the data (like firstname, lastname, birthdate)? In the controller? Are generic types a possible solution?

Cheerio

**Edit 18th October**

Thanks to user Palle for the support! The final solution would some kind look like this:

FormItem.swift

```
// enum with types for inputs
enum FormItemType: Int {
  case text = 0
  case date = 1
}

// enum with types of values
enum FormInputValue {
  case text(String)
  case date(Date)
}

// FormItem holds value, label and input
class FormItem: UIView {
  var value: FormInputValue?
  var label: FormLabel?
  var input: FormInput?
}
```

FormInput.swift

```
// Protocol to delegate the change to the controller
protocol FormInputDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
  func inputDidChange(value: FormInputValue)
}

// FormInput holds the actual input
class FormInput: UIView {

  var formInput: FormInput?
  var delegate: FormInputDelegate?

  // Init FormInput with type and optional value
  convenience init(type: FormItemType, value: FormInputValue?) {  
    switch type {
      case .text(let text)?:
        self.initTextInput(label: label, value: text)
        break
      case .date(let date)?:
        self.initDateInput(label: label, value: date)
        break
      case .none:
        break;
    }
  }

  // Init specific String input field
  fileprivate func initTextInput (label: String, value: String?) {
    formInput = FormTextInput(label: label, value: value)
    self.addSubview(formInput!)
  }

  // Init specific Date input field
  fileprivate func initDateInput (label: String, value: Date?) {
    formInput = FormDateInput(label: label, value: value)
    self.addSubview(formInput!)
  }
}
```

FormTextInput.swift

```
// Init actual input with label and optional value
convenience init(label: String, value: String?) {
  [...]
}
```

CreateViewController.swift

```
// Create View Controller where FormInputs 
class CreateViewController: UIViewController {

  var firstname: String = "Test 123"

  // Init view controller and add FormItem
  convenience init() {
    let fistnameFormItem = FormItem(type: .text, label: NSLocalizedString("Input.Label.Firstname", comment: ""), value: FormInputValue.text(firstname))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use separate inputs instead of one dynamic input.

If you really want a generic input, you can use enums with associated values for its value:

```
enum FormInputResult {
    case date(Date)
    case name(firstName: String, lastName: String)
}
```

In a Model-View-Controller architecture, data like names and birthdays should be stored in the data model. The controller should act as a mediator between model and view.

Comment: Well the plan was to have several form inputs in a view controller. A form input includes a label and one input of different types. As the controller holds the model, it is responsible to handle the returns from the form inputs.   So I thought the form input must return different types.

Comment: I would do that statically in interface builder. But of course you can do it in a dynamic way.

Comment: I'm not using interface builder or storyboard so I'm doing all of my interface and components from code. I added an edit with a sample source code, hopefully somebody can tell me what I'm getting wrong.

Comment: `FormInputValue` does not need to be generic, just declare it as `enum FormInputValue { ... }`. You have to destructure the value enum in the switch case statement to retrieve its associated values.

Comment: Ok so enum would be `enum FormInputValue {
  case text(String)
  case date(Date)
}`
and the initializer would be `convenience init(label: String, value: FormInputValue?)` where value is `FormInputValue.text(model.firstname)` right? But then in the `FormButtonInput` the `inputField.setTitle(value, for: .normal)` results in "Cannot convert value of type 'FormInputValue?' to expected argument type 'String?'"

Comment: You have to perform a pattern matching first: `switch value { case .date(let date): /* do something with the date */ case .name(firstName: let firstName, lastName: let lastName): /* do something with firstName and lastName */}`

Comment: Absolutely awesome @Palle. Thanks for your support. I updated the code above now with the working solution based on your comments.